# I am trying to scrap video details from a youtube channel using selenium but as a output i only get only one video details multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9B_ywLK2Vne4mtmGgWZklg/videos')

videos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'style-scope ytd-grid-video-renderer')

for video in videos:
    title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="video-title"]').text
    views = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[1]').text
    when = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="metadata-line"]/span[2]').text

    print(title, views)
```

Above code was expected to scrap videos details from targeted youtube channel but it only returns only details of first video multiple times!

Here is the output:
[This is the output!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um0WK.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="video-title"]').text
```

Should be

```
 title = video.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="video-title"]').text
```

.// Is what you'll use when xpathing from another element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension and do the job with something like this

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9B_ywLK2Vne4mtmGgWZklg/videos')

title = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#contents #items #video-title")]
views = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#contents #items #metadata-line span:first-child")]
when = [x.text for x in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#contents #items #metadata-line span:nth-child(2)")]
for i in range(len(title)):
    print(f'{title[i]} - {views[i]} - {when[i]}')
```